# Does this function series converge uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence

**Prove/Disprove:** If the functions $f_n (x)$ are monotonic for every $x \in [a,b]$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n (a)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n (b)$ absolutely convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n (x)$ is absolutely and uniformly convergent on [a,b].

Comment: Please show us some of your efforts to solve this problem if you expect us to help you.

Comment: I have thought of the counter example tan(nx) in [0,$pi$], but i am unsure if it holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, because you have normal convergence.

Proof: Let's note $f_n(a)=m_n$, $f_n(b)=M_n$ for each $n$.  Since $f_n$ is monotonic for each $n$, you can say that 
$$ \vert\vert f_n \vert\vert_{\infty} = \max(\vert(m_n\vert,\vert M_n\vert)  \leq 
\vert m_n\vert + \vert M_n\vert  $$

and the hypothesis is that $\sum_n \vert m_n\vert$ and $\sum_n \vert M_n\vert$ are absolutely convergent. So the inequality above shows that $\sum_n  \vert\vert f_n \vert\vert_{\infty}$ converges, i.e. $\sum_n  f_n $ converges normally, therefore uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Comment: (recall that normal convergence automatically implies uniform convergence: it's stronger)